# How do I select columns from two tables with differing layouts

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have the following two tables:

**CashRegister**

```
Date    PaymentId  CustId  VenId  Debit  Credit  Date
=========================================================
2/2/12  Pay_1      Cus_1                 444     3/2/2012
4/2/12  Pay_2              Ven_1  555
```

**SalesOrder**

```
SaleOrderId  CustId  Debit  Credit
==================================
So_1         Cus_1   666
```

From these two tables I have to generate a **Journal Report** like the following:

```
Date    TrId    AccountId  Debit  Credit
========================================
2/2/12  Pay_1   Cus_1             444   
3/3/12  So_1    Cus_1      666
4/2/12  Pay_2   Ven_1      555
```

I have tried this query:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM (
        SELECT Date, PaymentId, TrId, CustId, AccountId, VenId, AccountId, Debit,
               Credit
          FROM CashRegister

         UNION

        SELECT Date, SaleOrderId, TrId, CustId, AccountId, Debit, Credit
          FROM SalesOrder
        ) t
  ORDER BY Date
```

But it gives this error:

> In Union number of expressions should be equal for target list.

Comment: Add in 'empty' columns as required. The limitation *can't* be bypassed, so fake it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to use either CustId or VenId from the CashRegister table, and if so I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
    Date, 
    PaymentId AS TrId, 
    COALESCE(CustId, VenId) AS AccountId,  -- COALESCE returns the first 
    Debit,                                 -- non null value as AccountId
    Credit     
FROM CashRegister
UNION -- use UNION ALL if you don't want to eliminate duplicate rows.
SELECT 
    Date, 
    SaleOrderId, 
    CustId, 
    Debit, 
    Credit
FROM SalesOrder
ORDER BY Date
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51ab7/1)

Comment: But one thing @jpw, i had change the order of COALESCE(CustId,VenId) to COALESCE(VenId,CustId)... When i tried with your order , it showed a blank VenId, But when i changed the order, I was good

Comment: @Khan Good it worked. The order shouln't matter is the CustId was indeed null. If it was blank `''` coalesce would not work and you would have to use a case expression.

Comment: could you please explain how should I use case expression here?

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b42f7/1 The case expression in it will select the correct value if blank or null.

Answer (score 2):

To correct *your query* you have to add *stub columns* (`null` is usual stub value), e.g.

```
   select * 
     from (select Date,
                  PaymentId TrId,
                  CustId AccountId,
                  VenId, 
                  Debit,
                  Credit 
             from CashRegister

            union

           select Date,
                  SaleOrderId TrId,
                  CustId AccountId,
                  null,  -- Stub: there's no verdor id
                  Debit,
                  Credit
             from SalesOrder) t 
order by Date
```

However, it seems that the *right query* (that returns desired cursor) is

```
    select Date,
           PaymentId as TrId, 
           Coalesce(CustId, VenId) as AccountId, -- if CustId is null take VenId
           Debit, 
           Credit 
      from CashRegister
 union all -- I don't think you want to remove occasional dublicates
    select Date, 
           SaleOrderId,
           CustId, 
           Debit,
           Credit
      from SalesOrder
  order by Date
```

Comment: And the query returns a column more than asked for. Looking at the desired output I think what the OP wants is to get either CustId or VenId as AccountId.

Comment: yes @jpw it returns more than one column, i want either of CustId and VendorId

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to use either CustId or VenId from the CashRegister table, and if so I think this is what you want:

`SELECT 
    Date, 
    PaymentId AS TrId, 
    if(CustId<>'',CustId, VenId) AS AccountId, 
    Debit, 
    Credit

FROM CashRegister
UNION 
SELECT 
    Date, 
    SaleOrderId AS TrId, 
    CustId AS AccountId, 
    Debit, 
    Credit
FROM SalesOrder
order by Date;`

edit: 
Stack overflow formatting has stripped "<>" from my code. this will handle CustID beiang empty text, rather than just CustID being NULL.

Comment: _If_ does not wotk like this in TSQL; you need to use either _ISNULL_, _COALESCE_ or a _CASE expression_.

Comment: I think your answer is very much close to my solution, but its showing "incorect syntax near 'if'" could you please explain that

Comment: @jpw please explain your answer i didn't actually got that

Comment: Stack Overflow has stripped part of my code- not cool!! If you click "edit history" you can see the <> was there all along...